# Listbox Binding With No Results Listed

Tags: xaml, binding, listbox, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone App and I am trying to bind an ObservableCollection to a Listbox to list, at the moment, strings. However when I run the app nothing is listed and I cannot see where I am going wrong.

XAML:

```
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EventList}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Code-Behind:

```
    private ObservableCollection<String> eventList = new ObservableCollection<String>();

    public ObservableCollection<String> EventList
    {
        get { return eventList; }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        eventList.Add("Event One");
        eventList.Add("Event Two");
        eventList.Add("Event Three");

        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the DataContext of your main page to the application class that has EventList as a property? Set a break point on your get accessor and check if it is being called. If not, then you need to set the DataContext.